# How to make '/home' readonly?

Tags: operating-system, redhat, readonly, fstab

I have RHEL 7.5 installed and I wish to make both '/' and '/home' read-only. I have modified:
 - /etc/sysconfig/readonly-root so that 'READONLY=yes'
 - /etc/fstab so that /dev/mapper/rhel-root has 'ro' instead of 'defaults'.
 This works in making '/' readonly.

However I also wish to make '/home' readonly. Attempts at modifying /etc/fstab such that /dev/mapper/rhel-home has 'ro' instead of 'defaults' as well, results in a login loop. I also tried adding the user's home directory to /etc/rwtab.d/, which would then result in the system failing to load properly.

Are there any solutions in making '/home' readonly?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the command `sudo chmod a=r /home` or `sudo chmod 444 /home` while you are in "/" root directory.

Have you tried this one yet?

If you also wanted the changes to be recursive inside the /home just add `-R` from the above command.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have tried this but it resulted in a login loop (bounces me back to the login screen after logging in each time). Im guessing the OS is trying to write something under /home/<user> when you try to log in but it cant since its now readonly?

Comment: Exactly, there are process that writes some files(e.g session files) and saved it inside the user's home directory.